# How do I close stdin in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a misbehaving program that I need to call from my script. It exits as soon as it sees something on stdin. Is there a way to close stdin?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

#### Is there a way to close stdin?

> Closing File Descriptors
>
> - `n<&-` Close input file descriptor n.
> - `0<&-` or `<&-` Close stdin.

Source [Chapter 20. I/O Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

Comment: How to do it programmatically? What ASCII codes I must send to stdin to close it?

Answer (score 13):

Found it, you can close stdin with:

```
exec 0<&-
```

Answer (score 12):

Just pipe in a program with no output:

```
: | misbehaving_program
```

Comment: Wow, what is this? What does ':' do?

Comment: ":" is an internal command of the shell that does nothing.  It lets you introduce comments, or can be used for redirections.  For example ": > file" creates an empty file.  Or ": |" in this case feeds an empty stream to the command.

Answer (score 8):

According to what you say, you might fix your problem by simply

```
pickyProgram < /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

I found myself struggling with the same problem. My solution is derived from the suggestions here, but differ in that instead of closing `stdin` with `exec 0<&-` which allows for subshells to continuously use stdin. An example program that you would expect to exit but does not would look like:

```sh
exec 0<&-
$(read stdin)
```

This is because `read` is spawned inside a subshell inheriting `stdin` from the parent.
If we instead redirect the `stdin` we get the expected behaviour

```sh
exec 0</dev/null
$(read stdin)
```

This will yield an exit code 1.